# How to interpret the cut-off of a Mahalanobis distance in R

Tags: r, outliers, mahalanobis

Making the cut-off, I see two multivariante outlieres in the plot and get 4 numbers printet in my console.
(43 and 2 in the first row and 2 and 23 in the second row)

[image]

What do they stand for? How can I interprete the result? Are there cases, when I better not impute them or delete the entire row in the data set?

Comment: How did you generate these numbers?